# HTML Dropdown Default value not setting

Tags: php, html, combobox

I have a Dropdown that consists of two options. When I select an option the page reloads and using GET method I find out which value is selected. Then I try to make sure that the dropdown has the previously selected value and this is where things go wrong.

```
<?php echo $Status; ?>  <!-- the value passed in the URL(stored in the variable Status) gets correctly printed here -->
<select class="btn btn-primary" required name="Status" style="float:right" onchange="location = this.value">
      <option value="">Select Status</option>
          
      <option value="?pageno=1&Status='Active'"  <?php if($Status=='Active'){echo "selected";}?>>Active</option>
      
       <option value="?pageno=1&Status='Not Active'" <?php if($Status=='Not Active'){echo "selected";}?>>Not Active</option>
</select>
```

The value gets printed correctly in the first line but for some reason, it isn't working in the options part.  What am I doing wrong here? Can anyone clarify

Comment: Youur `Status` URL parameter does not contain `Active` or `Not Active`, it contains  `'Active'` or `'Not Active'`.

Comment: what says when you right click on page and see view page source ?

Comment: @AliFidanli
```
'Active'
<select class="btn btn-primary" required name="Status" style="float:right" onchange="location = this.value">
<option value="">Select Status</option>
<option value="?pageno=1&Status='Active'">Active</option>
<option value="?pageno=1&Status='Not Active'">Not Active</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @CBroe on Line 1 am printing the variable stored in Status, it's Active' then before the Active option is specifically checking if Status variable is Active or not. with same quotation marks too

Comment: _"with same quotation marks too"_ - no, _not_ with the same quotation marks. The value of your URL parameter is `'Active'`, and you are comparing your variable to the string value `Active`.

Comment: put else on if statements to see whats the value there

Comment: @CBroe why do you not write your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Geoffrey yeah, done. I wanted to give them a little time to figure it out themselves with the help of the previous comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of your URL parameter `Status` is either `'Active'` or `'Not Active'` - **including** those single quotes, they are part of the value that you are sending.

But what you are comparing it to, is just `Active` resp. `Not Active`:

```
if($Status=='Active')
```

The single quotes here are not part of the value that you are comparing `$Status` to - they are part of the *PHP syntax*. You would have to write something like

```
if($Status=="'Active'")
```

or

```
if($Status=='\'Active\'')
```

here, to properly compare the your variable with what it *actually* contains.

But that makes rather little sense to begin with - you should rather remove the single quotes from the parameter value you are sending.

```
<option value="?pageno=1&Status=Active"
<option value="?pageno=1&Status=Not+Active"
```

Note that I replaced the space with `+` here, to make this a properly URL encoded value.